# Issue with=> Add new project in Current Solution and move folder

Tags: visual-studio

•   hello friends,

•   I have one solution say “**sol1**’  which contain one project say “**proj1**”

•   Now I am adding one existing project say “**proj2**” inside this solution

•   Now I **moving the folder** which contain the “**sol1**” to the another **folder** or **drive**

•   And now when I start solution from that moved location I can’t getting the “**proj2**” which I have added later in “**sol1**”

•   Instead I am getting the error message and “proj2” displayed as grayed treeview node see in below image.

•   **What should I have to do if I want to add existing “proj2” permanently inside solution “sol1”.**

[image]

Thanks....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solutions contain the **relative** path to the contained projects. If the project directory isn't inside the solution directory, you'll run into this problem if you move the solution directory.

Either copy the project directory into the solution directory (giving you two copies, which might be undesirable) or fix up the project reference after you've moved the solution file.

You can do this by editing the .SLN file in a text editor. It's relatively easy to do, but the .SLN file format is fragile, so be careful. Or you can do it by bringing up the properties for the "broken" (greyed) project and editing the path. Then you can hit "Reload project" and you should be good.

Comment: thanks for answering , btw i have just noticed that if i adding "proj2" from another drive say if "sol1" is in "D" drive and "proj2" is in "E" drive...now when i adding "proj2" inside "sol1" then it adding the "Absolute Path" instead of "Relative Path" of "proj2". and also load "proj2" nicely if i moving the folder which contain "sol1" ..........Thanks......